# Compress data from pugixml

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, pugixml

I'm trying to compress data from a `pugi::xml_document`. This is what I tried :

```
template<class T> void save(const T &object, const QString &path)
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    object.exportXML(doc);

    std::ostringstream stream;
    doc.save(stream);

    QByteArray data = qCompress(stream.c_str(), 9);

    QFile outfile(path);
    outfile.write(data);
    outfile.close();
}
```

But it doesn't work because `doc.save()` takes a `ostream` and not a `ostringstream`. How can I get the tree formated to a string from the `xml_document` and compress it using `qCompress`?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the no-stl define is commented in *pugiconfig.hpp* file:

```
// Uncomment this to disable STL
// #define PUGIXML_NO_STL
```

The stringstream header include is required:

```
 #include <sstream>
```

That said, watch out: you're calling a non existing method `c_str()` directly on the `std::ostringstream` object, and not on its underlying string, returned by `str()` (and your compiler output should be something like: *no member named 'c_str' in 'std::basic_ostringstream'*).

Your code should be like this:

```
QByteArray data = qCompress(stream.str().c_str(), 9);
```

Comment: As I said the method `save()` takes an `ostream` object no an `ostringstream` which gives me an error.

Comment: ostream is a direct base of ostringstream, please post your compiler output

Comment: `error: no matching function for call to 'pugi::xml_document::save(std::ostringstream&)'`
For the doc : https://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#saving.stream

Comment: It's commented. :/

Comment: I also have these errors: `error: 'std::ostringstream stream' has incomplete type` and `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::ostringstream {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>}'`

Comment: Edited again. Check your includes.